# Flutter Error on assigning List Name to a variable of type list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have following code

```
class PWData {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  // final String party;
  final String designation;
  final String partySymUrl;
  final double partySymW;
  final double partySymH;
  final String pwPicUrl;
  final bool display;

  PWData({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
//    required this.party,
    required this.designation,
    required this.partySymUrl,
    required this.partySymW,
    required this.partySymH,
    required this.pwPicUrl,
    required this.display,
  });
}

final List <PWData> HaryanaStateData = [
  PWData(
    id: 'pw1',
    name: 'Haryana State Rajiv Singh Kataria',
    partySymUrl: 'assets/party_icon/bjp1.png',
    designation: 'MLA',
    pwPicUrl: 'assets/pw_pictures/amitabha.jpg',
    partySymW: 30,
    partySymH: 30,
    display: true,
  ),
  PWData(
    id: 'pw2',
    name: 'Haryana State Fist Last02',
    partySymUrl: 'assets/party_icon/congress1.png',
    designation: 'MLA',
    pwPicUrl: 'assets/pw_pictures/dharmindra.jpg',
    partySymW: 30,
    partySymH: 30,
    display: false,
  ),];


class StateRecord {
  final String Stateid;
  final String StateName;
  final List <PWData> DataFile;
  final bool Status;

  const StateRecord(
      {required this.Stateid,
      required this.StateName,
      required this.DataFile,
      required this.Status});
}

final StateList = [
  const StateRecord(
    Stateid: "state01",
    StateName: "Andaman & Nicobar Island",
    DataFile: HaryanaStateData,//<----------Getting error here
    Status: false,
  ),];
```

Android Studio is not allowing following assignment & underlining the the statement in red

//DataFile: HaryanaStateData,

Where I am wrong? kindly help to correct this. Can't we store List name in a List Variable?
My idea is to use DataFile name to access respected data file for a state.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `const`. `StateList` should look like:

```dart
final StateList = [
   StateRecord(
    Stateid: "state01",
    StateName: "Andaman & Nicobar Island",
    DataFile: HaryanaStateData,
    Status: false,
  ),];
```